# Trigger.io Urlhandler - Deep Linking with Facebook

Tags: facebook-android-sdk, trigger.io

Deep linking for Android apps on Facebook allows apps to be opened directly upon clicking a open graph story or other link on FB.

The required settings for this are:

- Package Name
- Class Name ("The Class Name of the activity you want Facebook to launch")

The package name is user-configurable in the Trigger web interface and I have that correct, however I have no idea what the Class Name is, because handler classes are not directly written.

I've tried "urlhandler", "ForgeActivity", and my custom urlhandler scheme ('fb[APP_ID]' as per FB documentation).

In all cases Facebook launches the Play store instead of the app which is already installed and authorised. This is the expected fallback behaviour if the Package Name is correct but class name is not.

What is the class name I can use for Trigger to handle launching from Facebook?

Answer (score 1):

The class name for the main activity in Trigger is `io.trigger.forge.android.core.ForgeActivity`.

I've not tested it but I believe with that setting deep linking will open your app, but it doesn't use the urlhandler so unfortunately there will be no way for you to receive and handle the deep link url.

Comment: Sorry for not replying sooner - this activity name does not open the app at all, but even if it did it wouldn't solve the problem since you mentioned it won't trigger urlhandler.

Thanks for answering anyway, I would mark this as correct if it opened the app.